# Using John Resig's "simple JavaScript inheritance" how can I call a super method PLUS extra code from within a method?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, extend, resig

I decided to try out JavaScript genius John Resig's "simple JavaScript inheritance" as detailed on this blog page:

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

I'm curious how one might override a method with code that calls the super method. In other words, let's say I start with a **Person** class:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    init: function ( name, age ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
});
```

I extend that **Person** class to create a new class **Worker**:

```
var Worker = Person.extend({
    init: function ( name, age, occupation ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }
});
```

There's repetition of code in the two versions of the *init* method. The following two lines are executed no matter which class I'm using:

```
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
```

It seems like I should be able to call the **Person** class's *init* method from within the **Hero** class's *init* method and then throw in the extra line of code with the *occupation* property.

I can't do that with Mr. Resig's code, though. The following doesn't work:

```
var Worker = Person.extend({
    init: function ( name, age, occupation ) {
        this._super(arguments);
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }
});
```

As soon as the *extend* method called from **Person** to create the **Worker** class sees *this._super(arguments)* it replaces the entirety of **Worker's** *init* with **Person's** *init* leaving me with an undefined *occupation* property.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get around this without having to modify Mr. Resig's code? I'm currently trying out different ways to implement the concept of a "super," but the fact that I can't get this to work with the existing code is stuck in my head. :-)

UPDATE: I realized that I made one small error in implementing Mr. Resig's code which is why this behaved the way I described. @chuckj correctly pointed out an error in **Worker's** *init*, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the Worker definition to,

```
var Worker = Person.extend({ 
    init: function (name, age, occupation) { 
        this._super(name, age); 
        this.occupation = occupation; 
    } 
});
```

you don't pass the `arguments` array, you call the `_super` with the parameters it expects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your goal is to proxy the `arguments` to `this._super`. In this case you can just `apply()` them :

```
var Worker = Person.extend({
    init: function ( name, age, occupation ) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }
});
```